# Quicker way to output the content of a tuple in a print statement

Tags: python, tuples

I would like to print the contents of a tuple with a print statement like this:

```
print("First value: %i, Next four values: %i %i %i %i, Next three values: %i %i %i\n" % (myTuple[0], myTuple[1], myTuple[2], myTuple[3], myTuple[4], myTuple[5], myTuple[6], myTuple[7]));
```

Now as you can see in the example above the elements in a tuple are going to be output in order, but the format is such that you can't easily use a loop. Is there a way to just specify the whole tuple/list/set (or a given range) in print statement without specifying each element separately, something like this?

```
 print("First value: %i, Next four values: %i %i %i %i, Next three values: %i %i %i\n" % (myTuple[:7));
```

Comment: Have you tried it? (Note that `(myTuple[0], myTuple[1], myTuple[2], myTuple[3], myTuple[4], myTuple[5], myTuple[6], myTuple[7])` is itself a 8-tuple.

Comment: @Amadan Yeah you are right, I should have tried it first. Didn't think this would possibly be a right syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `str.format()`, which you probably should be, you can use the iterable-unpacking operator `*`:

```
myTuple = tuple(range(10))
print("There are 7 values {} {} {} {} {} {} {}".format(*myTuple[:7]))
# There are 7 values 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

If using old-style format strings, you can just give `my_tuple[:7]` as the argument, since it expects a tuple or other iterable after the `%`:

```
print("There are 7 values %i %i %i %i %i %i %i" % myTuple[:7])
# There are 7 values 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.format`:

```
a = (1,2,3,4)
print("first {}, second {}, thrid {}, forth {}".format(*a))
#first 1, second 2, thrid 3, forth 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one way you could iterate, group, and print through your tuple. This would allow you to print sequences of numbers beyond 1, 4, then 3.

```py
from collections.abc import MutableSequence

def group(values, limits):
    '''
    Group sequence of values into bins of size limit

    Parameters
    ----------
    values : Sequence
    limits : List or tuple of limits
        Sizes of each group

    Notes
    -----
    First group is of size 1

    Returns
    -------
    Tuple of grouped values
    '''
    def _rm_select(limit):
        '''
        Slice and delete value from sequence
        '''
        yield values[:limit]
        del values[:limit]

    def _group(values, limits):
        '''
        See `group`
        '''
        # Yield 0th value with slice fo 1
        yield from _rm_select(1)
        for limit in limits:
            yield from _rm_select(limit)

    # Check if sequence is mutable
    # . If not, convert to `list`, in order for `del` to function
    if not isinstance(values, MutableSequence):
        values = list(values)

    return tuple(_group(values, limits))

def printer(groups, descriptions):
    '''
    Print each group with a prefixing description.
    '''
    def _stringify(groups, descriptions):
        '''
        See `printer`
        '''
        for description, group in zip(descriptions, groups):
            group = ' '.join(str(i) for i in group)
            yield f'{description} {group}'

    string = tuple(_stringify(groups, descriptions))
    print(*string, sep=', ', end='\n\n')

values = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
descriptions = ('First value', 'Next four values', 'Next three values')

groups = group(values, limits=(4, 3))
printer(groups, descriptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

A format string is a good tool if you do not mind an extra pair of parentheses:

```
myTuple = ((1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10))
print(f"First: {myTuple[0]}, next: {myTuple[1:]}")
# First: (1, 2), next: ((3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10))
```